# Uncheck all checkboxes in a group when "Any" checkbox is checked used to work not working anymore

Tags: javascript, checkbox, getelementbyid

I have this JS that has been working fine for a while, and I have no idea why it is not working anymore now. It is supposed to uncheck Any (checked by default) when any number of other checkboxes is checked, and uncheck whatever is checked if Any is checked.

```
/**
 * Define a set of checkbox groups
 */
var locations = new Array('A', 'P', 'PR', 'GR', 'MC', 'F', 'S', 'L', 'LU', 'E');
/**
 * Checking the "anyId" checkbox clears the rest of the group.  Checking any other clears the "anyId" checkbox.
 */
function toggleBoxes( el, anyId, group ) {
    var i;
    if ( el.id == anyId ) {
        for( i = 0; i < group.length; i++ ){
            var cb = document.getElementById(group[i]);
            cb.checked = false;
        }
    } else {
        var cb = document.getElementById(anyId);
        cb.checked = false; 
    }
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div class="input">
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='anyLocation' name="ts-in_pr" value="any" type="checkbox" checked>Any</p>
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='A' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="AR" type="checkbox">Ao</p>
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='P' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="PI" type="checkbox">Pa</p>
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='PR' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="PO" type="checkbox">Po</p>      
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='GR' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="GR" type="checkbox">Gr</p>
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='MC' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="MC" type="checkbox">MC</p>                                                                  
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='F' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="FI" type="checkbox">Fi</p>
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='S' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="SI" type="checkbox">Si</p>
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='L' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="LI" type="checkbox">Li</p>
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='LU' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="LU" type="checkbox">Lu</p>
            <p><input onClick='toggleBoxes(this, "anyLocation", locations)' id='E' class="geoloc" name="ts-in_pr[]" value="El" type="checkbox">E</p> 
        </div>
```

What happens is that Any is unchecked fine when any other box is checked, however when it is checked back it only unchecks the three boxes right below (which values are Ao, Pa, and Po). All others are kept checked, and when they are unchecked manually, they also uncheck Any (if it was checked). I had this JS custom made, and I have no clue what is going wrong with it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://jsfiddle.net/bMUsK/

Comment: Working fine for me! Code wise too this looks good.

Comment: @josiahruddell you defined `locations` variable as a property of the `window` object, thus making it global. Copy the code @Lucas used exactly, and you will see that it will work only if you put it inside head, and it will fail onLoad.

Comment: I am using this in a wordpress installation, might be that Jquery or another JS is messing up with it?

Comment: @Lucas, most likely, since if you paste this exact code inside of a jQuery's document ready closure it will not work, but then you can do what @JosiahRuddell proposed

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell thanks will try your suggestion

Comment: @ArtBIT - I was hoping that @Lucas's error was not as blatant as an undefined javascript error and that the error was somewhere else in the page. It is a possibility though.

Comment: @all The issue was the fourth ID was not spelled the same as in the Array definition. Upon reproducing the code for you I wrote it correctly, but on the website two letters got inverted, possibly during a recent update. I did check the code a million times. Apologies for raising a fuss for nothing and thanks all for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code must be in the head, or on the top of the body tag, but either way your variable `locations` needs to be global since every time you call `toggleBoxes`, `locations` will be undefined.

Check the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/DBanG/

Comment: No i try this on local and this is not true, I mean you can put this js code every where and it works the same

Comment: @Lucas is probably using the above code inside a closure, most likely in some kind of a `onDomReady` handler. And since locations is defined as a local variable, everytime a `toggleBoxes` function is called, `locations` will be undefined.

Comment: I tried it in the head and I get the same issue. And I saw you jsfiddle link, so it seems to be working fine as a standalone. Do you know any kind of "safe wrap" to shield it from onDomReady handlers? (no idea what they are)

Comment: Thanks will try that and see what happens.

Comment: @Lucas That way you're basically making the `locations` and `toggleBoxes` globally visible, by making them properties of the window object.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have duplicate id somewhere in document (possibly "GR"). Try using prefix in order to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. I have simplified your function parameters a bit. The code that I see doesn't need the second and third parameter since they are constant.

http://jsfiddle.net/srEuM/

Bob

Comment: Thanks. However, those are parameters needed for a plugin the form is passing variables to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. I tested it locally and no problem.